# MonoObject to c++ bool

Tags: mono-embedding

I have embedded the mono runtime into my C++ application.
The C++ code calls a C# method which returns a bool value.

How can I get the bool value from the returned MonoObject?

```
MonoObject* res = mono_runtime_invoke(my_method_instance, processor_, nullptr, nullptr);
bool result = *how does this work??*;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just found the solution in the Embedded Mono documentation (http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/).

```
int int_result = *(int*)mono_object_unbox (result);
```

This also works for bool values

```
bool value = *(bool*)mono_object_unbox(result);
```